# MySQL Round Robin Select

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of urls. I need to select 1, in round robin. Hoping to display 1 per pageview OR per Visitor and show each 20 times if I have 100 pageviews OR Visitors.

Essentially: `SELECT url FROM table LIMIT 1` (in rotation)

```
+-------+---------------------+
| id    | url                 |
+-------+---------------------+
|     1 | http://google.com   |
|     2 | http://yahoo.com    |
|     3 | http://ebay.com     |
|     4 | http://anything.com |
|     5 | http://other.com    |
+-------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Do not clear your question please explain with expected output.

Comment: "in round robin" means id 1, then later id 2, then later id 3 ... etc for a particular user? You would need to store which was the last item displayed against the user.

Comment: @Sadikhasan `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1` But that 1 record has to be selected in rotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you mean by round-robin then you can do something along the lines of

```sql
SELECT id, url
  FROM urls u CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT MIN(id) min_id, MAX(id) max_id
    FROM urls
) m 
 WHERE id > IF(? >= max_id, 0, ?) -- last shown id goes here instead of placeholders
 ORDER BY id
 LIMIT 1;
```

Store (in session, file, another table, etc.) and pass to your query the last shown `id` or 0 for the initial query.

This will give you the next row or first again if you reached the last one.
This query will still work if you have gaps in `id`s.

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6059d/13)** demo

Comment: This looks promising, I'll test it today.

Comment: @webaholik How did your test go?

Answer (score 3):

You can do using `order by rand()`

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`RAND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) function in your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Best solution so far! However I would like to guarantee equal amount of selects for each record.