# Limit entries to MySQL table, keep unique id fixed

Tags: php, mysql, database, backend

I'm posting this here in the hope that someone can give me some ballpark advice as I am a frontend and don't know PHP/MySQL well.

I've heard of triggers but I'm not sure if they are appropriate for my use case. This is more of a conceptual question, before I start the code. Please be kind, I'm a novice :)

I have built a table set up like so:

```
+-----------+-----------+-------+
| UNIQUE ID | Anchor    | URL   |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
| 1         | link name | [url] |
| 2         | link name | [url] |
| 3         | link name | [url] |
| 4         | link name | [url] |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

This is linked up to an HTML form where a user can set custom links to appear in a menu.

I would like it to be the case that the MySQL table can only ever have four rows and the unique IDs stay constant and are not overwritten. However the 'Anchor' and 'URL' rows can be overwritten.

This is so that I can have a permanent hook on the row (via a `WHERE uniq_id=x` `SELECT` rule) whilst allowing the user generated data to change.

I want it to be the case that the link output to the front end will always be the last one set by the user.

I have really searched but no one seems to've had a similar request which implies I may be going about this completely the wrong way. Grateful if someone could direct me to the right track. Thank you.

Comment: Have a timestamp column that records the time the row gets updated. Then disable INSERTs on the table and simply execute UPDATEs on the oldest row.

Comment: If I understand right you are looking to implement [round robin in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056870/mysql-round-robin-select)?

Comment: What version of MySQL is this for?

Comment: Hi thank you. I am using MySQL 5.1.73

Comment: @Strawberry this was the ticket. Thanks. Implementing now. Will update answer for others when tested.